# Component is not rendering the output when navigating back from different component (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous

I am facing difficulties rendering array on screen when I navigate back to the component. I have been trying and searching since morning for the solution but no luck. Please let me explain

I have a react component called ShowTags.tsx that contains a callback function handleTagReading() which return strings every second (async behavior).

When the string tag arrives I am storing it in [storeTags] state array and in the return method, using map function to iterate and display the tags.

The Sample code

```
export default function ShowTags() {
    //array to store string tags
    const [storeTags, setStoreTags] = useState<String[]>([]);
   
   //callback method 
   const handleTagReading = (tag) => {
      console.log("print the tag" + tag) // this line runs everytime
      setStoreTags(storeTags => [...storeTags!, tag]);
   }

    return (
        <>
            /*This component contains a button, on button click it runs the loop method which runs 
               the parent callback method*/
            <ReadTags parentCallback = {handleTagReading} />
          <div className="container">
            {storeTags && storeTags!.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                   {item}
                </div>)
             })}
      </div>
      </>
      )
  }
```

This code works perfectly as long as I am on The ShowTags component for the first time. The moment I navigate to a different component and come back, the map method shows nothing. But console.log() still runs showing the tags coming from a callback.

I have tried using the useEffect(), cleanup(), boolean states variables, non state variables but  the component does not render when switching back to ShowTags component.

Please help me out here and let me know if you need more information

**UPDATE -edit**
For simplicity I said async behavior but actually I am using Serial USB API to read data from RFID reader (external hardware device connected via USB)

The ReadTags() component contains lot of code but I am sharing the necessary bits

```
export default function ReadTags(props) {

//send diffenent commands to reader on button press
async function sendSerialLine() {
     try{
        await writer.write(dataToSend);
     }catch(e){
        console.log("the write error")
        setShowConnect(true)
     }
  }
  //The listenToPort method runs continuously when the RFID reader gets connected via Serial USB and does not stop. 

  async function listenToPort(){
    /*serial USB API implementation*/
    textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
    readableStreamClosed = port.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
    reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();
   
    while (true) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            reader.releaseLock();
            break;
        }
        //parent callback
          props.parentCallback(value);
    }}

 return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={() => sendSerialLine()} className="btn btn-primary">Start Reading</p>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Please can we see the ReadTags component?

Comment: Hi @squish I have updated my question

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `useCallback` with `handleTagReading`

Comment: I just tried it. Still same thing. I don't understand if console.log() is showing the output then why the state is not changing.

Comment: Please explain your answer. **Why** should OP "Try to use useCallback with handleTagReading"?